# Can I offer nimaz in a room where i had previously masturbated many times?

Tags: quran, salat

I want to pray in my room and also recite quran but previously i had masturbated in my room. Is it permissible to offer prayers and recite quran in the same room now ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if the place  where  you want to pray is not napak(impure).